# Reset Panel components inside Form

Tags: wicket

I have a Wicket Form and in this form there are components and panel(contains few components). When i do reset using formComponent.clearInput(), it resets only form components but not components inside panel.

Please let me know how to reset panel components also.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your components should be driven by the same model objects that are behind the form. That means you don't need to explicitly reset them at all, only add them to the `AjaxRequestTarget` if you want to refresh them during the serving of an ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

`FormComponent.clearInput()` clears the request parameter that feeds this form component, a.k.a. its `input`. And it clears only this form component.

You have to use `Form.clearInput()` to clear the inputs for all FormComponent's in this Form.

Answer (score 0):

```
FeedbackPanel.getFeedbackMessages().clear();
```

Read more 
[Component API](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#getFeedbackMessages()) and [FeedbackMessages API](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/feedback/FeedbackMessages.html#clear())